# Werkzeug-0.9.4 and python3_memcached-1.51 doesn't work on Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, flask, memcached, werkzeug, python-memcached

I'm using `werkzeug.contrib.cache.MemcachedCache` with python3_memcached-1.51 when I try to get\set data I get the following error: `memcache.MemcachedKeyTypeError: Key must be str()'s` here:
https://github.com/eguven/python3-memcached/blob/master/memcache.py#L1039

```
if not isinstance(key, str):
    raise Client.MemcachedKeyTypeError("Key must be str()'s")
```

The key type is `bytes`, not `str`. So I checked deeper.

Inside `werkzeug.contrib.cache.MemcachedCache` key is encoded into `bytes` (in Python3) like this:

```
if isinstance(key, text_type):
    key = key.encode('utf-8')
```

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/contrib/cache.py#L342

What is correct fix for this? Monkey patch?

Comment: I'd [raise an issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues) with the Werkzeug project instead.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues/539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to upgrade to Werkzeug 0.10: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/commit/94bea60a1b8e26b586dcd7bc75b162a9909696a3